# Redirect all resources on Azure to custom domain

Tags: c#, azure, redirect, web-config

I'm hosting a website on Azure. You get a free domainname in this form mydomain.azurewebsites.net. I want to forward this domain to a custom domain, www.mydomain.com. I wrote this rule in web.config:

```
<rule name="Redirect old-domain to new-domain" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain.azurewebsites.net$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="www.mydomain.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

This did the trick, but only for the homepage. When I go to mydomain.azurewebsites.net it will redirect tot www.mydomain.com. But when I go to mydomain.azurewebsites.net/page1/name1, there is no redirect. Is it possible to redirect alle pages to my custom domain, so mydomain.azurewebsites.net/page1/name1 has to redirect to www.mydomain.com/page1/name1.

Comment: Hi Sven - did you get a solution to this problem...  I have the same issue with Google having indexed the azure URL and not my custom domain.

Answer (score 0):

The usual method for this is to redirect your domain to the Azure domain. Either as an Alias or as an A record pointing to the IP address. That was nobody ever actually sees the Azure domain name, or ever needs to know of its existence you simply have example.com and Azure replies to those queries.

In order to do this you will need to verify your domain name with Azure but that is simply a matter of creating a new CNAME record in DNS.

Comment: Thanks, but that happened already. But the azure domain is already in Google, so I have to forward everything to my custom domain. It has to be possible in web.config but dont know how...